# c programmin arrays and pointers

Tags: c, pointers

I have not coded in c in a while, and I never was very good with pointers.

i have this beginning for main.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
```

I need to be able to make a copy of the *argv[] in a global scope to allow multiple threads to access it, Is there a fast/easy way to do this?

Comment: Programming in C == knowing pointers like the back of your hand.  Learn all about them :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it:

```
char **     prog_argv;
int         prog_argc;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    prog_argv = argv;
    prog_argc = argc;
    . . .
}
```

This declares a global pointer `prog_argv` that points to your `argv[]` array. Note that you also should use a global `prog_argc` to be on the safe side (although I think that `argv[argc]` is a null pointer (?)).

Of course, you need to declare `prog_argv` and `prog_argc` in a header file for the benefit of your other project source files.

Some operating system already do something like this for you. The names of the global variables are usually something like `_argv` or `__argv`.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to *copy* the `argv` array (given to `main`). You only need to transmit the pointer to it to your threads. This is quite easy (by passing it thru arguments, or by having some global variable containing it).

Comment: then pthread_create (&thread1, NULL, do_thread_stuff, *argv); This is what I was trying but getting errors, any suggestions of what I am doing wrong?

Comment: I think it should be `pthread_create (&thread1, NULL, do_thread_stuff, arg)` without any star.